# Адаптивная верстка (Bootstrap 5)

Tags: javascript, html, css, css3, html5

Я знакомлюсь с **бутсрапом 5** , и вот научился как-то применять классы на разрешения под разные дисплеи, типа классами sm-md-lg... и т.д.

Вроде по-тихоньку получается, только вот у меня почему-то не меняются размеры шрифтов под размеры экранов и кнопки, я искал в библиотеке Bootstrap 5 , но не нашел таких классов или решении.
Если посмотрите на **navbar** сверху, то после 760px ширины экрана, то правая кнопка корзины уходит, как быть, чтобы все размеры уменьшались ровно?
Например, как [lamoda](https://www.lamoda.kz/c/477/clothes-muzhskaya-odezhda/?sitelink=topmenuM&l=2), если уменьшите их сайт до малых размеров, сайт равномерно уменьшается, вот такой эффект хотел бы  получить.

Такая же проблема с картинками, при уменьшении размера экрана, почему-то первый столбец таблицы чуть больше, чем остальные две, почему так получается?
Как можно установить на картинки ,с немного отличающимися размерами, одинаковые свойства, которые будут меняться в соответствии с размерами экранов?
Спасибо заранее!

Comment: Бутстрап намеренно не включает в себя утилити-классы для изменения размеров шрифтов, и в его документации это объясняется (насколько я помню).

Comment: @yar85 Здорова, да я заметил, теперь сижу и меняю размеры)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Делается это например вот так

```css
div {
  font-size: 10vw;
}
```

```html
<div>СУПЕР ТЕКСТ<div>
```

Или вот так

```css
div {
  font-size: 25px;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 500px) {

   div { 
  font-size: 15px; 
   }

}
```

```html
<div>СУПЕР ТЕКСТ<div>
```